# Remove the dash from [tag:big-table]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging, retag-request

The tag [big-table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-table), per its description, refers to [Google Bigtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigtable) (without a dash). Would it be possible to remove the dash?

The current version appears to look like it's referring to "large [database] tables" which is leading it to be misapplied to questions in some cases, e.g., [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130888).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Would it be possible to remove the dash?

Sure. Renamed [big-table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-table) to [bigtable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bigtable) for you.

Answer (score 2):

Since there are only 13 questions linked to the [big-table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-table) tag, it's likely easier to simply create [bigtable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bigtable) and edit the existing questions to use the new tag.  Any tag that is unused will eventually be automatically removed by the StackExchange system.

Comment: Creating a tag [requires 300 rep](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), which the OP does not have.